# What is the most pythonic way to import 'sibling' modules into one another?

Tags: python, python-module

By 'sibling' modules, I mean two submodules that exist at the same depth within a parent module.

I'm trying to create a flask project using Flask-Restful, and it recommends structuring the project using this schema:

```
myapi/
    __init__.py
    app.py          # this file contains your app and routes
    resources/
        __init__.py
        foo.py      # contains logic for /Foo
        bar.py      # contains logic for /Bar
    common/
        __init__.py
        util.py     # just some common infrastructure
```

I really like this structure, but I'm not sure how to import something from the 'common' module into the 'resources' module.  Can anyone help me out?

Comment: If you import `foo.py` and `bar.py` into `resources/__init__.py`, I'm pretty sure you can just do `from myapi.resources import Foo, Bar`. If you want to do the opposite, same logic applies.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In `common/__init__.py`

```
from myapi.common.utils import A, B
```

In `resource/foo.py`

```
from myapi.common import A
```

You can also relative imports in `__init__.py` like `from .utils import A`.